# amsthm environment and colorbox

Tags: color, boxes, theorems, amsthm

I'd like to customize the `amsthm` command a little bit but I cannot find the relevant lines in the (undocumented?) .sty.

1. How can I put a colorbox on the *name* of the environment

   ```
   \newtheoremstyle{Coloredtheo}%
   {3pt}    %Space above
   {3pt}    %Space below
   {}       %Body font
   {}       %Indent amount
   {\bf \colorbox{blue}}    %Theorem head font
   {}       %Punctuation after theorem head
   {0.25em} %Space after theorem head
   {}       %Theorem head spec
   ```

   where the blue box should be of the size of the theorem head.
2. how I can remove the brackets of the optional parameter

   `\begin{theorem}[Schwarz inequality]...` should not be (Schwarz inequality) but Schwarz inequality.

Comment: The documentation for amsthm is in the file amsthdoc.pdf.  It's probably in your distribution.  Try "texdoc amsthm" from a command line.

Comment: @Matthew -- the *user* documentation for `amsthm` is in `amsthdoc.pdf`.  the *source* documentation is in `amsclass.dtx`. `amsthm` is built into the ams document classes, and the `.sty` file is spun off from that source. since everything is interwoven, it may be a bit obscure to pull out just the `amsthm` parts, but it's all there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{Coloredtheo}%
{3pt}    %Space above
{3pt}    %Space below
{}   %Body font
{}   %Indent amount
{\bfseries}    %Theorem head font
{}   %Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em} %Space after theorem head
{\colorbox{\thmbgcolor}{\color{\thmheadcolor}\thmname{#1}%
  \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}}%
  \thmnote{ {--- \the\thm@notefont#3.}}%
}   %Theorem head spec
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{Coloredtheo}
\newtheorem{genericcolorthm}{\generichead}
\newenvironment{colorthm}
  {\def\generichead{Theorem}%
   \def\thmbgcolor{blue}%
   \def\thmheadcolor{red}%
   \begin{genericcolorthm}}
  {\end{genericcolorthm}}
\newenvironment{colorlemma}
  {\def\generichead{Lemma}%
   \def\thmbgcolor{green}%
   \def\thmheadcolor{black}%
   \begin{genericcolorthm}}
  {\end{genericcolorthm}}
```

With two commands in the theorem style definition, you are free to give them a meaning which will be local in the environment.

Answer (score 3):

> 1 - How can I put a colorbox under the
>   name of the environment ... where the
>   blue box should be of the size of the
>   theorem head.

Take a look at the [`thmtools`](http://ctan.org/pkg/thmtools) package.  It gives a nice key-val interface to declaring all kinds of beautiful theorem-like environments.

Answer (score 2):

> 2 - how I can remove the brackets of the optional parameter
>
> ```
> \begin{theorem}[Schwarz inequality]...
> ```
>
> should not be (Schwarz inequality) but Schwarz inequality.

Put this in the preamble:

```
\newtheorem*{schwarz}{Schwarz Inequality}
```

Then in the document:

```
\begin{schwarz}
% ``I see your Schwarz is as big as mine.'' --- Dark Helmet, Spaceballs
\end{schwarz}
```

**EDIT** I think I understand what you want now.  If you don't want a one-off environment, you can alter the theorem's head specification to typeset only the theorem note (optional argument) without delimiters, like so:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{namedtheorem}%
{3pt}    %Space above
{3pt}    %Space below
{}   %Body font
{}   %Indent amount
{\bfseries}    %Theorem head font
{.}   %Punctuation after theorem head
{0.25em} %Space after theorem head
{\thmname{\@ifempty{#3}{#1}\@ifnotempty{#3}{#3}}}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{namedtheorem}

% first argument here is the environment to be defined
% second argument is the default name of the theorem.
\newtheorem*{namedtheorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}

\begin{namedtheorem}
One is the loneliest number.
\end{namedtheorem}

\begin{namedtheorem}[Schwarz Inequality]
For $x$ and $y$ in a Hilbert space $H$, 
\[
    |(x,y) | \leq \Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert
\]
\end{namedtheorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it is not optional anymore

Comment: @pluton: Not sure what that means.  What exactly do you want to type and see?

Comment: I do not want the optional argument of a math environment to be between brackets in the pdf. The name of the environment should still be something like "theorem" or "definition" or "lemma".

Comment: not exactly :) I want (for instance) "Theorem 1.2 --- Schwarz inequality." instead of "Theorem 1.2 (Schwarz inequality)" (which is by default)

Comment: OK, never mind.  I see you have that in your own answer.