# Color highlighting text and environments in LyX

Tags: color, lyx, environments, highlighting

I am using LyX 2.0.5 with document class `article` and 'Theorems (AMS)' in the modules. I am wondering if it is possible to make it so that the titles of different environments will be highlighted in different colors ("highlighted" in the sense of a highlight marker. I.e., having a colored background, w/o changing the font color). E.g., in the `Theorem` environment the words **Theorem 12.1** will be typeset with red highlight, in the `Definition` environment the words **Definition 5.9** will be typeset with yellow highlight, etc.

I am guessing the will require changing the module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Note: there are parts of this solution that are sub-optimal, and I'm aware of that, but I'll have to fix that later. I'll remove this note when I find the time to improve things.)

You can change the files `theorems-ams.module` and `theorems-ams.inc`, or better create copies as described in my answer to [How to make "claim" environments look like "theorem" environment?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/129770/how-to-make-claim-environments-look-like-theorem-environment/129779#129779)

In `theorems-ams.module`, add `xcolor` to the required packages. I.e. where it says

```
Requires    amsmath,amsthm
```

edit this to

```
Requires    amsmath,amsthm,xcolor
```

(This bit is untested, but I assume it will work.)

In `theorems-ams.inc`, find the style you want to change, for example the block defining the look of theorems starts with `Style Theorem`.

In the `Style` block there is a sub block `Preamble`, which by default looks like

```
Preamble
    \theoremstyle{plain}
    \newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}
EndPreamble
```

Using code taken from [egreg's answer to *amsthm environment and colorbox*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15269/586), edit this to read

```
Preamble    
    \newtheoremstyle{Coloredtheo}%
    {3pt}    %Space above
    {3pt}    %Space below
    {}   %Body font
    {}   %Indent amount
    {\bfseries}    %Theorem head font
    {}   %Punctuation after theorem head
    {0.25em} %Space after theorem head
    {\colorbox{red}{\color{black}\thmname{#1}%
      \thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}}%
      \thmnote{ {--- \the\thm@notefont#3.}}%
    }   %Theorem head spec
    \theoremstyle{Coloredtheo}
    \newtheorem{thm}{\protect\theoremname}    
EndPreamble
```

Note that this will not change the view in LyX, only in the PDF. Do similarly for `Definition`, but use a different name for the `\newtheoremstyle`. The background colour is set by the first argument to `\colorbox`, here `red`.

For a single document, you could use the Local layout under Documents --> Settings. Add the entire `Style` block to the local layout. You may need to also include `\usepackage{xcolor}` to the `Preamble` block.

Comment: Thanks! But actually I meant "highlight" in the sense of having the background colored (like with a highlight marker), w/o changing the text color. I will edit the original post to make it clearer.

In any case, I tried your solution but it only changed the font color in LyX (and not in the PDF output). Am I missing something?

Comment: @doodle I edited my answer. It's not perfect, but I think it's closer to answering your question now.

Comment: Amazing! One little thing though: The dot that usually appears after the theorem number is gone. I tried changing `{}` to `{.}` in the `%Punctuation`, but this adds the dot outside of the color box.

Comment: OK, got it. I changed `\@upn{#2}}` to `\@upn{#2}}{.}` in your code. That took care of that dot.
//
Also, I kept the `Color   Red` parameter under `Label Font`, which you mentioned before your edit. It's not what I was looking for as far as end result in the PDF, but it does make LyX look slightly more like the PDF. Thanks again!